# Dropdown navigation

Tags: css

Hello I am trying to create a dropdown navigation menu in my website flexbox based. The problem is when I style the dropdown menu the links are all on top of each other. Here is the piece of code that's giving me problems.if someone can please help I would appreciate it. The .sub is the second ul. I am also following along with a youtube video.

!

```
DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Home | Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <link

      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text&display=swap"

      rel="stylesheet"

    />

  </head>

  <body>

    <header>

      <img src="img/logo/internet.png" alt="" />

      <div class="hamburger">

        <div class="line-1"></div>

        <div class="line-2"></div>

        <div class="line-3"></div>

      </div>

      <nav>

          <ul>

              <li><a href="">Home</a></li>


              <li><a href="#">Portfolio

                  <span class="arrow">&#x25bc;</span>

                  <span class="right">&#x25b6;</span>

              </a>

                <ul class="sub">

                    <li><a href="">Web Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Game Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Software Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">App Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Progressive Web App Dev</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>


              <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>

              <li><a href="#">Cases

                <span class="arrow">&#x25bc;</span>

                <span class="right">&#x25b6;</span>

              </a>

                <ul class="sub">

                    <li><a href="">Web Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Game Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Software Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">App Dev</a></li>

                    <li><a href="">Progressive Web App Dev</a></li>

                </ul>

            </li>


            </li>

          </ul>

      </nav>

    </header>

    <main></main>

    <section></section>

    <footer></footer>

  </body>

  <script

    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"

    integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc="

    crossorigin="anonymous"

  ></script>

  <script src=""></script>

</html>



nav a {

    color: #fff;

    display: block;

    height: 64px;

    font-family: Crimson Text;

    display: flex;

    align-items: center;

    justify-content: center;

    text-decoration: none;

    transition: background 0.4s;

  }


  nav a:hover {

    background-color: skyblue;

  }


  nav ul {

    list-style: none;

    display: flex;

  }


  nav li {

    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;

    position: relative;

  }


  nav .right {

    display: none;

  }


  nav li:hover .sub > li {

    display: block;

    top: 0;

  }


  .sub li {

    display: none;

    position: absolute;

    top: 0;

  }

.sub {
Display: flex;
Flex-direction: column;
Position: absolute;
Width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please provide minimal code to recreate it here. You can post it in a snippet. :)

Comment: Please also provide us the HTML markup code